# Setting BitmapImage.UriSource to inexistent Uri doesn't raise error

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, bitmapimage

I'm trying to create a WPF Image programmatically, but whatever string I put in the Uri contructor, it's not raising any error... even if it can't find the file:

```
BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri("/blah;component/Themes/buh.png", UriKind.Relative);
logo.EndInit();
Image im = new Image() { Source = logo };
```

How can I test if the Uri I wrote really exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the bitmap isn't loaded until it is shown on screen (e.g. by adding your `Image` control to some visible container in your application).

You could however force immediate loading by setting `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`. Now `EndInit()` will throw an exception.

```
var logo = new BitmapImage();
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri("/blah;component/Themes/buh.png", UriKind.Relative);
logo.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
logo.EndInit();
```

---

That said, you should not use `UriKind.Relative` when retrieving image resources. Instead use a proper [Resource File Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) like

```
logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/blah;component/Themes/buh.png");
```